# Issue retrieving character from a string variable in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to retrieve the second character from a string variable:

```
string myString = "Hello"
string secondChar = myString[1]
```

However, instead of getting "e," the result is "Hello." What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` in `pinescript` is called [history-referencing operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#history-referencing-operator). It is used to access historical values of a variable.

You can convert your string to an array with the `str.split()` function and then access the chars with `array.get()`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

string myString = "Hello"
myStringArr = str.split(myString, '')
secondChar = array.get(myStringArr, 1)

if (barstate.islast)
    label.new(bar_index, high, secondChar)
```

[image]